# How is allocated memory handled when kill command for a process is given?

Tags: c++, unix, operating-system

Suppose I am running my application.During this in my code memory allocation has taken place for various objects . Now i execute a kill command on my unix terminal for the process. In that case how does all the memory deallocation process takes place ? Is this handled entirely by the operating system by deallocating the entire memory for the process ?

Comment: A [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its own [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). When the process is terminated, that address space (and the physical memory it is consuming, and some other resources) is destroyed (to be reusable) by the kernel.

Comment: Memory isn't necessarily the only resource you should be concerned with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418338/heap-memory-clearance-when-application-closes-abruptly

Answer (score 3):

In general, at process termination, all resources allocated by this process are freed by operating 
system. 
(see 3.3.2 
**Operating System Concepts** by Abraham Silberschatz , Peter B. Galvin, Greg Gagne 
 [http://www.amazon.com/Operating-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0470128720](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720))

The kill command does not "kill" process, but sends signal to it.  If the signal is  **SIGKILL** (kill -9 PID) you can do nothing. Process is killed unconditionally.  If signal is **SIGTERM** (default), you can serve it or ignore it. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal